# Bootstrap 3 Strange Column Issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, blogger

I've been working on creating a blogger theme for my blog using bootstrap and everything seemed to be going great. It's a two column layout with the main column being set with sm-8 and the sidebar column being set to sm-4 so they both line up.

My problem is that everything looks great on the homepage, but if i click on a post to view just that alone, the side bar column breaks from the row and floats at the bottom of the page. I've never had this problem before so was wondering if any of you guys have encountered it.

```
    <div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-8'>
      <b:section class='main' id='main' name='Main' showaddelement='no'>
        <b:widget id='Blog1' locked='true' title='Blog Posts' type='Blog'>
        </b:widget>
      </b:section>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-4'>
      <b:section class='' id='sidebar' maxwidgets='20' name='Sidebar' showaddelement='yes'>
        <b:widget id='FeaturedPost1' locked='false' title='Featured post' type='FeaturedPost'>
        </b:widget>
        <b:widget id='CustomSearch1' locked='false' title='Search:' type='CustomSearch'>
        </b:widget>
        <b:widget id='PopularPosts1' locked='false' title='Popular Posts' type='PopularPosts'>
        </b:widget>
      </b:section>
    </div>
    <!--end col-->
  </div>
  <!--end of row-->

</div>
<!--end of main container-->
```

Here is a link to the testing site I've been developing it on http://mytestblogfortheme.blogspot.co.uk/

If you click the post titles you will see what I mean.

Comment: Please post your code here. Once the problem has been fixed, this question is useless for future reference.

Comment: As a post script to the above, it looks like you have a misplaced `</div>` tag on your `single.php` template.

Comment: The blogger html editor won't let you save anything unless all tags are closed off properly. It's very strict.

Answer (score 0):

Is simple in the first page your template keep in the same row both the `col-8 and th col-4 <div>` (you can inspect with a browser html code inspector like firebugs)

in the second page (by clicing on post title)  your template  keep in row only the `col-8 <div>` and for this reason the col-4 div is move bottom under the row div

You can move the col-4 column of the second page template inside the row

Comment: The code above is applied to all pages of the blog. Blogger doesn't let me create a seperate html file for each page. At least not that I know of anyway. Thanks for the help though, it is appreciated.

Comment: The code above don't seems like i insepected in you second page .. try with firebugs .. in the second page (the one by clicking of post title) the rows div end before of col-4

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. Because that code is used in every page, and for some reason the col-4 div stays where it should on the homepage but breaks from the row when viewing a single post, which is no wider than the blog roll on the homepage. It's very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by using a table to keep the two columns together when viewing a single post:

```
  <div class='row'>
<table><tr><td>
<div class='col-sm-8'>
  <b:section class='main' id='main' name='Main' showaddelement='no'>
    <b:widget id='Blog1' locked='true' title='Blog Posts' type='Blog'>
    </b:widget>
  </b:section>
</div>
<div class='col-sm-4'>
  <b:section class='' id='sidebar' maxwidgets='20' name='Sidebar' showaddelement='yes'>
    <b:widget id='FeaturedPost1' locked='false' title='Featured post' type='FeaturedPost'>
    </b:widget>
    <b:widget id='CustomSearch1' locked='false' title='Search:' type='CustomSearch'>
    </b:widget>
    <b:widget id='PopularPosts1' locked='false' title='Popular Posts' type='PopularPosts'>
    </b:widget>
  </b:section>
</div>
<!--end col-->
</td></tr></table>
```

Not an ideal solution I agree, but it does the job for now.